# How can I change text selection/highlight color (usually ::selection) in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, text, selection

I'd like to change it from the default blue and can't seem to find anything on this. The usual doesn't work:

```
::-moz-selection, ::selection {
    background: #AFAFAF;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `background-color` instead of `background`?

Comment: I actually hadn't thought of this and got really excited - unfortunately it still doesn't work. I did notice that when I had some text selected, and then "unfocused" to the URL bar (while it was still selected), the selection did go from blue to grey (the colour I want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::-moz-selection` and `::selection` are browser specific pseudo classes. If one vendor browser(chrome) doesn't understand other vendor browser's prefix, it ignores the rules under that block. So it is recommended to separate browser specific pseudoclasses.

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: #AFAFAF;
}
::-webkit-selection {
  background: #AFAFAF;
}
::selection {
  background: #AFAFAF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nutboltu/hgumjs95/7/

Answer (score 1):

Because they're both scopes you can not define them both in one style definition.  Separate them into 2 separate styles and it will work.

```
::-moz-selection{
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
::selection{
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble setting the selection-specific CSS pseudo-elements in React directly. Managed to get this working by defining the selection styling in a CSS file and setting the color as a CSS variable from React.

CSS:

```
.styled-div {
  ::-moz-selection {
    background: var(--selection-color);
  }
  ::-webkit-selection {
    background: var(--selection-color);
  }
  ::selection {
    background: var(--selection-color);
  }
}
```

React (typescript):

```
const selectionColor = "#ABABAB";
const divStyle = { "--selection-color": selectionColor } as React.CSSProperties;
return (
  <div className="styled-div" style={divStyle}>
  </div>
);
```